# Make all grid children visible in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling, hidden-field

I have a website with a grid item that reveals hidden children as the page is scrolled (i.e., scroll down and see more images).

I am trying to grab the text (video views) related to each image and put it in an array.
This works fine for the images *currently* on screen, but not for the hidden ones.

For example,

```
const allVideoCountEl = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".DivItemContainerV2 .video-count"));

var a = [];
allVideoCountEl.forEach(videoCountEl => {
  a.push(videoCountEl.innerText);
})
```

will tell me there are 70 items, but if I actually scroll to the bottom of the page there are 690 items.

How can I modify this to grab all 690 items without manually scrolling down the page?

Comment: It sounds like the page uses AJAX to fetch items from the server dynamically when you scroll. So they're not in the DOM yet when you call `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Or maybe it only adds the `video-count` class to the item when it makes it visible. Use a class that doesn't change dynamically depending on the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't hidden grid elements in the end, it was infinite scroll.
The solution was to scroll to the bottom, wait a few seconds and scroll again:

```
window.scroll(0, 10000000);

setTimeout(() => {
  window.scroll(0, 10000000);
}, 3000);

setTimeout(() => {
  window.scroll(0, 10000000);
}, 5000);
```